# R: How to use functions to generate part of function arguments

Tags: r

I came up with this question when I am using the stargazer package in R to present the regression results of several regressions together. Suppose I have 3 (actually I have much more) regressions with names reg1,reg2,reg3. The traditional stargazer way to show would be `stargazer(reg1,reg2,reg3,(other options))` .

I am wondering if there is any method that generates all the "reg1 to reg3" and then use the output to replace the part in the stargazer argument. I tried something like `sprintf("reg%d",seq(1:3))`. However, Stargazer seemed to treat the output simply as a string.

I also tried `eval(parse(text=cat(paste("stargazer(", paste(sprintf("reg%d",seq(1:3)),collapse = ","), ", type = \"text\")"))))`, but R gets stuck.

Is there a method to make this work? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to use `do.call` with `mget`.

Base R `do.call` creates a function call for the first argument and the list elements of the second argument are converted to the arguments of that function.

`mget` will create a named list from objects in the calling environment. In this case, it finds `reg1`, `reg2`, and `reg3` in the global environment and makes them into a list. We can combine that list that `mget` creates with our own manually defined list with `c`.

```
do.call(stargazer, c(mget(sprintf("reg%d",seq(1:3))),other.parameters)))
```

In this case, `other.parameters` should be a named list of other arguments you want to pass. For example

```
other.parameters <- list(type = "latex")
```

Comment: Hi Ian, Thank you for your answer. I tried your solution, but R gives the error message "second argument must be an environment". Then I figured out that the correct solution is `do.call(stargazer, c(mget(sprintf("reg%d",seq(1:3))), other.parameters))`, which I think you actually meant. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try passing the second command into stargazer:

```
reg_models <- sprintf("reg%d",seq(1:3)) %>% noquote()
reg_models

[1] reg1 reg2 reg3

cat(paste(reg_models, collapse=", "))
reg1, reg2, reg3
```

Comment: Hi Latlio, I am sorry but your suggestion was very similar with what I did in the original question. I figured out the correct way to do this with the help of Ian. Your can refer to his answer and my comments. Thank you all the same!